# How to use an array index as an operator?

Tags: c

How to use an array index as an operator?

Such that:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    char sign[]={'+','-'};
    int a, b;
    a = 12 sign[1] 10;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Actually this code doesn't work. What will be the right code for this type of programs?

Comment: I think the idea is creative, no need to downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest is to use a switch statement or if-else chain.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char sign[]={'+','-'};
    int a,b;

    switch (sign[1]) {
        case '+':
            a = 12 + 10;
            break;

        case '-':
            a = 12 - 10;
            break;
    }

    printf("%d",a);
}
```

If I was doing this, I'd probably end up moving some of the logic into a function though. Perhaps something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int perform_operation(char op, int lhs, int rhs) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return lhs + rhs;

        case '-':
            return lhs - rhs;

        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char sign[]={'+','-'};
    int a = perform_operation(sign[1], 12, 10);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: +1, but evil to use `operator` as that's a keyword in C++ and OP may port the code one day.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It's an easy enough change.

Comment: Heard that before. A sum of easy changes = refactoring hell.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not strictly dependent on the infix notation, you'll be able to make it simply by

```
int plus(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int minus(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int (*)(int, int) sign[]={plus, minus};
```

and you'll be able to use that as:

```
int a = sign[1](10, 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use function pointers:

```
//function:
int addInt(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

//define the pointer:
int (*functionPtr)(int,int);

main ()
{
  functionPtr sign[5];
  sign[0] = &addInt;

   int a = 5, b = 8;
  //...
  int sum = sign[0](a,b);
  printf("%d", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

It's a little bit more complicated, and in most simple cases, you would want to use a switch statement to call different functions, but this is a very useful method when dealing with larger, more complex cases.

An example of when I've used arrays of function pointers like this was when developing an image processing application, with vendors providing the algorithms for some pretty special processing.
Their code was proprietry though, and so while we could attain dlls containing functions that could do the processing, we couldn't build it into our code.  As any number of these dlls may be required, and we wanted the ability to add-remove functionality without re-compiling the entire system, we needed to be able to read the dlls and manage them.  We used a method like above for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use a ternary for this:

`a = 12 + (sign[1] == '-' ? -1 : +1) * 10;`

Of course this defaults to `+` but you could introduce earlier checks to guard against that.

You could use this to form a macro:

`12 + SIGN(1) 10;`

with

`#define SIGN(s) (sign[(s)] == '-' ? -1 : +1) *`

which recovers the form of the expression in your question excepting the square brackets.