# How to use char array index's permutations as operator?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, operators

please look at my c++ program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char sign[]={'+','-','/','*'};

int i,j,k,l=0;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<=3;k++)
        {
            if(sign[j]!=sign[i]&&sign[k]!=sign[i]&&sign[k]!=sign[j])
            {

            printf("%c %c %c\n",sign[i],sign[j],sign[k],l);

            }

        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

the output of this program is like this..

```
+ - /
+ - *
+ / -
+ / *
....
```

I want to use them between numbers...
 like this..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char sign[]={'+','-','/','*'};

int i,j,k,l=0;
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<=3;k++)
        {
            if(sign[j]!=sign[i]&&sign[k]!=sign[i]&&sign[k]!=sign[j])
            {
                int l;
                l=18sign[i]12sign[j]4sign[k]5;
                printf("18%c12%c4%c5=%d",sign[i],sign[j],sign[k],l);

            }

        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I want the output like this..

```
18+12-4/5=29
18+12-4*5=10
18+12/4-5=16
18+12/4*5=33
.....
```

then what will be the code for this??
[I can't use switch tag because for that I will have to declare 24 cases. Is there any way to use the indexes as operator??]

Comment: `Is there any way to use the indexes as operator` Nope, thank goodness.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: you can create an array with pointers to functions for your operators

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730365/boost-lambda-example for an example in C++11 on how to have a factory that could return a lambda to do the operation based on the sign

Comment: Wait, wasn't this asked yesterday too? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26718585/4022608

Answer (score 2):

No.

C (and C++) are *static* compiled languages. You can't make decisions at run-time that require different code to be present, since the compiler is no longer around to generate that code.

In C++ you can do various template tricks to make the compiler generate code for various cases at compile-time, but it's not quite clear how that would apply, here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct exp {
    char op;
    char *term;
    struct exp *left;
    struct exp *right;
} Exp;

Exp *make_exp2(char *str){
    if(!str || !*str) return NULL;//*str == '\0' is format error.
    char *mul = strrchr(str, '*');
    char *div = strrchr(str, '/');
    Exp *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if(mul == NULL && div == NULL){
        node->op = '\0';
        node->term = str;
        node->left = node->right = NULL;
        return node;
    }
    char *op;
    op = mul < div ? div : mul;
    node->op = *op;
    *op = '\0';
    node->left  = make_exp2(str );
    node->right = make_exp2(op+1);
    return node;
}

Exp *make_exp(char *str){
    if(!str || !*str) return NULL;//*str == '\0' is format error.
    char *minus = strrchr(str, '-');
    char *plus  = strrchr(str, '+');
    if(minus == NULL && plus == NULL)
        return make_exp2(str);
    char *op;
    Exp *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    op = minus < plus ? plus : minus;
    node->op = *op;
    *op = '\0';
    node->left  = make_exp(str );
    node->right = make_exp(op+1);
    return node;
}

int multiplication(int a, int b){
    return a * b;
}
int division(int a, int b){
    return a / b;
}
int addition(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
int subtraction(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}

int calc(Exp *exp){
    switch(exp->op){
    case '*' :
        return multiplication(calc(exp->left), calc(exp->right));
    case '/' :
        return division(calc(exp->left), calc(exp->right));
    case '+' :
        return addition(calc(exp->left), calc(exp->right));
    case '-' :
        return subtraction(calc(exp->left), calc(exp->right));
    default :
        return atoi(exp->term);
    }
}

void drop_exp(Exp *exp){
    if(exp){
        drop_exp(exp->left);
        drop_exp(exp->right);
        free(exp);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char expstr[128];
    sprintf(expstr, "18%c12%c4%c5", '+', '-', '/');//18+12-4/5
    Exp *exp = make_exp(expstr);
    printf("%d\n", calc(exp));//30
    drop_exp(exp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an expression parser in order to handle the correct operator precedence. Look at [Infix Calculator Expression Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853774/infix-calculator-expression-parser) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {18, 12, 4, 5};
    char signs[] = {'+', '-', '/', '*'};
    std::map<char, std::function<int(int, int)>> m = {
        {'+', [](int a, int b){ return a + b; }},
        {'-', [](int a, int b){ return a - b; }},
        {'/', [](int a, int b){ return a / b; }},
        {'*', [](int a, int b){ return a * b; }},
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(signs), std::end(signs));

    do {
        int res = m[signs[2]](m[signs[1]](m[signs[0]](numbers[0], numbers[1]), numbers[2]), numbers[3]);

        std::cout << numbers[0] << signs[0] << numbers[1] << signs[1]
            << numbers[2] << signs[2] << numbers[3] << " = " << res << std::endl;

    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(signs), std::end(signs)));
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/OqUphX)